# why might rails-2.3.5 not reload some files under app in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dependencies, development-environment

I've added a subdirectory `app/renderers` after Railscast #101. The classes in that directory are not getting reloaded by my development server. It's driving me a little bonkers.

I've read everything I could find on forcing it to reload lib and/or plugins but this seems to be a different case since "everything under app should be reloaded automatically." Plus, I've checked `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_once_paths`, and `app/renderers` definitely isn't in it.

I'd also like to get the renderers to be automatically required, so that I don't have to go around putting require statements in the rest of my code. Is that sensible? How does it work for, say, models and other constants?

Answer (score 2):

Doh. I should have been **loading** the files, not requiring them.

I'd still like to have them magically loaded -- not needing a specific load statement for each one -- but for now it's working :)